# Where was the Banach-Mazur Theorem originally published?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request

I would like to cite the original source for the Banach-Mazur Theorem that the space $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ of continuous functions on the unit interval is universal for separable Banach spaces, i.e., that for every separable Banach space $X$ there is an isometric embedding $i\colon X\to\mathcal{C}([0,1])$. In the books on functional analysis I have there is no reference to the original proof of this result.

In short my question is: where was the Banach-Mazur Theorem published originally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kleiber and Pervin (1969)](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FBAZ%2FBAZ1_02%2FS0004972700041411a.pdf&code=ca2fbbcbc66494157005a5003ed21b36) cite Banach's monograph Théorie des Opérations Linéaires (1932) for the "*classical theorem of Banach and Mazur*". Here is a [scanned copy of the original](http://kielich.amu.edu.pl/Stefan_Banach/e-operations.html) edition (in French) on Banach's home page. There is an [English translation](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486469832.html) available from Dover.

Comment: For easier navigation, this is Theorem 9 in Chapter XI. It does not seem to correspond to any earlier published joint work by Banach and Mazur. They did publish several papers on the problem of a linear normed space being isomorphic to a subspace of another one, e.g. Zur Théorie der linearen Dimension, Studia Mathematica 4 (1933), 100-112, available from Banach's homepage, http://kielich.amu.edu.pl/Stefan_Banach/oeuvres.html